# Python - .insert() method only replaces the first letter of word?

Tags: python, tkinter, desktop-application

I've posted about this before and I've been able to whittle the program down to a single function for testing purposes. I'm not getting any errors, but I am getting a bug that is driving me up the wall. I'm able to replace the shortcut, but it only replaces the first letter of the shortcut.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

syntax = "shortcut = sc" # This will be turned into a function to return the shortcut
                         # and the word, I'm only doing this for debugging purposes.

def replace_shortcut(event=None):
    tokens = syntax.split()
    word = tokens[:1]
    shortcut = tokens[2:3]

    index = '1.0'
    while 1:
        index = text.search(shortcut, index, stopindex="end")
        if not index: break
        
        last_idx = '%s + %dc' % (index, len(shortcut))
        
        text.delete(index, last_idx)
        text.insert(index, word)
        
        last_idx = '%s + %dc' % (index, len(word))

text.bind('<space>', replace_shortcut)
text.mainloop()
```

The shortcut given, in our case 'sc' will turn into 'shortcutc' after the space is typed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `index` and `last_idx` are what you're assuming they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

You have the variable `shortcut` defined to be `['sc']` instead of `'sc'`.  So `len(shortcut)` will always be 1 (the length of the array) rather than 2 (the length of the string).  You'll always end up deleting just one character. Probably you want `len(shortcut[0])`

[You also have the same problem with `len(word)`.  You'll always get 1, the length of the array.]

Also, the last line of your while loop should set `index` rather than `last_idx`, since that's the variable that's going to be used in the next search.

Comment: (Updated my answer.  I just realized that `word` has the same problem as `shortcut`)

Comment: that worked! I'm a little new to Python and didn't know strings could get that meticulous. Thank you for your help!